# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties (decimal and double, with rounding)

Tags: c#, int, double, decimal, ambiguous

My program cannot determine whether to execute `Math.Round` as a `decimal` or a `double`, but I have no idea how to fix this... Here is my code, though the second to last line is what I am concerned with.

```
 ArrayList topp1 = new ArrayList();
 int toppcount = 0;
 foreach (Control cb in GroupBoxH1T.Controls)
 {
     CheckBox cb1 = cb as CheckBox;
     if (cb1.Checked == true)
     {
          toppcount++;
          topp1.Add(cb1.Text);
     }
  }

  if (cbhwchoice.Checked == false)
  {
      ArrayList topp2 = new ArrayList();
      foreach (Control cb in GroupBoxH2T.Controls)
      {
          CheckBox cb1 = cb as CheckBox;
          if (cb1.Checked == true)
          {
              toppcount++;
              topp2.Add(cb1.Text);
          }
      }

      toppcount = Math.Round((toppcount/2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Math.Round` expects a floating point or decimal number because calling it on an integer would have no effect.  If you want to call it, pass in a value of that type.  To do so, you can simply cast the numerator and denominator to the desired type.  For Example:

```
decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(toppcount) / 2.0M;
toppcount = Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: You can shorten it by much if you just do: `toppcount = Math.Round(toppcount / 2m, MidpointRound.AwayFromZero);`. The `2m` causes all the necessary casts.

Answer (score 1):

In the second last line

```
 toppcount = Math.Round((toppcount/2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

`toppcount` is `integer`
`2` is also `integer`
so `toppcount/2` will give you `integer`
as example  `1/2` will give you `0`

try `Convert.ToDecimal(toppcount)/2.0`
or
`(Decimal)toppcount/2.0`

Answer (score 0):

Replace integer 2 with decimal 2.0 in last statement of the if block. So the statement will become like this:

```
toppcount = Math.Round((toppcount/2.0))
```

Comment: Dear NatNgs because the answer from bitoshi.n is talking about explicit conversion. I also faced same problem. I got idea from the bitoshi.n's answer. So i thought of putting it simple so that others get more clear idea.